# AngularJS - página não encontra o controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, undefined

Estou começando a testar aplicações utilizando AngularJs e Spring Boot.

O meu problema é o seguinte:
Todos os scripts são importados normalmente no navegador, mas SE coloco a tag "ng-controller="HeadController"" em qualquer tag da minha página, tenho um erro falando que "HeadController" não é uma função.

O meu código em HTML é o seguinte:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title>{{title}}</title>        
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="HeadController">
        <p>Qual seu nome?</p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        <p>Olá, <span ng-bind="name"></span></p>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/controllers/HeadController.js"></script>
    </body>  
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="../css/bootstrap-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" src="../css/bootstrap-theme-min.css">
```

O meu main.js é:

```
angular.module('mod', ['ngRoute', 'HeadController']);
```

O meu HeadController é:

```
angular.module('mod').controller('HeadController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.title = 'titulo';    
});
```

Todos os scripts são importados corretamente na página. 
Utilizo Freemarker como template engine.

O problema que encontro é o seguinte:
[Erro](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=HeadController&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined)

ALguém saberia me ajudar com isso?

Agradeço desde já,

Comment: Já tentou carregar os scripts antes do body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adicione o `ng-app` na sua tag html: `<html ng-app="mod">`, e remova a injeção do seu controller no seu módulo, deixando seu main.js assim: `angular.module('mod', ['ngRoute']);`

Comment: Funcionou direitinho Brunno, brigadão!